# Karate not defined when running custom Gradle Test Task

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, karate

I'm getting a `Karate not defined` error when trying to run my Karate tests outside of the main/default `test` task.

I've tried many ways and combinations:

```
task customTask(type: Test (or) GradleBuild, dependsOn: [build (and/or) test]) {
  // finalizedBy throws an exception saying it's an invalid option
  filter {
     ...
  }
  // tasks = ['test'] when using GradleBuild
}
```

So essentially my question is: How can I run karate tests `outside` of the default `test` task.

I want to define `custom` filters without using the `CLI` so I can kick off tests by my custom Gradle tasks

Clarification as to why I want to use custom gradle tasks for this:

I have built a Gradle script that builds karate scripts based on json config file and a template folder with multiple karate and js files.
The output is multiple directories + sub-directories based on the configuration containing separate Runners and Feature Files.

Due to business requirements tags would be very long as they have to match specific features (30+ characters long). This would be okay, however I would then like my "test generating script task" to generate those "testByTag" tasks as well as we're talking about 100+ tests. Doing this manually through the cli every time makes this process cumbersome.

Comment: Can you explain more about why you want to make a custom mechanism for doing what Karate and Gradle already do by using tags?  Why move away from the test task?

Comment: I pass on this question. have asked some gradle users if they know the answer.

Comment: @user3486382 updated my question for clarification

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm at the end of my usefulness here.  At the end of the day this is recoding something that Gradle/Karate already do, so I don't see it as being worth the time your spending on it.  Use tags and rework your test strategy, that's the best help I can give you.  Good luck.

Comment: @user3486382 thanks for your help anyway! Then let me ask you this: How can I run karate tests, selected by tasks, in gradle, with the click of a mouse button in IntelliJ (as in: no manual cli command required?)

Comment: I use VS Code, and I live on the CLI, so again not much help.  But, if you're doing anything in any CI/CD system then you want to use the CLI anyway, in most cases.  If you're not on CI/CD then I recommend looking into it.  Running test locally or with UI should only be done while debugging specific test scripts.  Ideally you would have options in the CI/CD UI so users can choose tags and such when they kick off the tests.  And if you're running tests in-line with a product build pipeline you would have the tests tagged for versions or features, etc.